# Odoo 13: Post Inventory valuation in past dates

Tags: inventory, odoo-13

I am using Odoo v13 enterprise and my inventory configuration is - FIFO, Automated.

I am importing sales orders and delivery orders from a different system into Odoo.

When importing SO and DO i am setting date same as in other system also accounting entries are generated with same date as of DO but valuation entry(stock valuation layer) is generated with the current datetime when creating record as stock.valuation.layer is using create_date as date.

I tried to pass context from delivery order and verified it in create and write but it didn't worked. Can we change this date somehow to match actual delivery date instead current datetime.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You might do this with script. A possible way to process each step by step and update date in the same script. As it is FIFO automated so if you later on than valuation might get wrong. You need to do the process step by step and update the date in same execution.

Comment: I tried in same module right after delivery done. I tried with create(), write() and other methods but create_date does not change.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Does it affect anywhere if I change create_date via query?

Comment: Yes it possibly it affects.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with a self.env.cr.execute query using UPDATE, it should give.

Comment: Please expand on your answer.  It is not clear what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a query to the base:

```
parameters= []
parameters.append(parameters_date) # date to data
parameters.append(id_stock_valuation_layer) # object id

self.env.cr.execute("UPDATE public.stock_valuation_layer SET create_date=%s WHERE id=%s ",(parameters))
```

the date must be type datetime!!